# React Hook Toggle class on window resize

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener

I'm trying to build a simple mobile menu with an event listener that would remove the toggle class 'is-open' whenever the window resizes (on the body, button and menu). Not too confident about the syntax, the toggle seems to work but i can't seem to put the pieces together. Any help would be very kindly appreciated!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function NavigationMobile() {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(window.innerWidth < 991);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('is-open', isOpen);
  },[isOpen])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      const ismobile = window.innerWidth < 991;
      if (ismobile !== isMobile) setIsMobile(ismobile);
    }, false);
  }, [isMobile]);

  return (
    <Wrapper>

      <button className={`nav-link btn-icon menu ${isOpen ? 'is-open' : ''}`} onClick= {toggle} aria-label="Open Menu">
      </button>

      <div className={`mobile-menu ${isOpen ? 'is-open' : ''}`}>

        <div className="mobile-menu-inner">
       
        </div>

      </div>

    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default NavigationMobile;
```

Comment: isMobile is not triggering your useEffect since its not changing when you resize the window, it only changes once when you start your page, but why do you care about doing all that? just trigger the button on the very first load

Comment: What about something like this https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/

Comment: @Frosty lol yes i know, i couldn't figure out how to join both. The problem resides in the fact that i open the menu and resize to a higher width, it disappears with the css right, but if i come back, the menu stays open, which is something i would like to prevent

Comment: Why are you not using CSS for handling different breakpoints? Why do it in Javascriptland?

Comment: It is set,  at 992px it's in display none, the menu will stay open if it hasn't been closed when you resize

Comment: because the toggle class "is-open" is still applied

Comment: Well, I meant you can use CSS to handle showing/hiding the menu, all outside of Javascript, no need to conditionally add/remove classes. But if you are programatically updating some component state it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frosty is correct, this works though:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const NavigationMobile = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
                setIsMobile(true);
            } else {
                setIsMobile(false);
            }
            console.log(window.innerWidth);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <button
                className={`nav-link btn-icon menu ${isOpen ? 'is-open' : ''}`}
                onClick={toggle}
            />

            <div className={`mobile-menu ${isOpen ? 'is-open' : ''}`}>
                <div className='mobile-menu-inner' />
            </div>

            {!isMobile && <h1>Not Mobile</h1>}
            {isMobile && <h1>Is Mobile</h1>}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default NavigationMobile;
```

Comment: Hmn, not too familiar with Fragment, might sound super silly as a question but is that to replace the <Wrapper> (i use Styled Components) or is there a specific usage in this case?

Comment: yes you can a fragment is an empty tag the same as `<></>` (please accept my answer for reputation!)

Comment: Oups sorry, just did!  Thank you by the way, i was able to test it but added the setIsOpen to false

Comment: `  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
        setIsMobile(true);
      } else {
        setIsMobile(false);
        setIsOpen(false);
      }
      console.log(window.innerWidth);
    });
  }, [isMobile]);`

Comment: Great! Glad i could help